# Java - How to check whole array for intersection

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I wasn't sure how to really ask this question so I just made a new thread. I'm trying to see if I can instantaneously check if my ball intersects with any rectangle in an array.

```
if(ball.getBounds2D().intersects(bricksEasy)) <-- bricks easy is a 2D array of rectangles
```

Right now I'm avoiding just iterating through the whole array to avoid delay. Any solutions I could use? Appreciate it.

Comment: *"I'm avoiding just iterating through the whole array to avoid delay."* - That reasoning makes no sense. Either you or some existing code needs to iterate and as you already found out, there is no such existing code. So there is only _you_ left who can iterate that array.

Answer (score 1):

> Right now I'm avoiding just iterating through the whole array to avoid
>   delay. Any solutions I could use?

It will not cause any delay if you stop iterating as soon as you detected a collision.

If you manipulate a `Rectangle2D` instance, you could use this overloaded instance method :

```
public boolean intersects(Rectangle2D r)
```

And to exit from the iteration as soon a match is done, you could use the `anyMatch()` predicate :

```
Rectangle2D ball2D = ...;
Rectangle2D[] bricksEasy = ...;
boolean isAnyIntersection = Arrays.stream(bricksEasy).anyMatch(brick -> brick.intersects(ball2D));
```

You can also do it by using a method reference with the `ball2D` variable as target of:

```
Rectangle2D ball2D = ...;
Rectangle2D[] bricksEasy = ...;
boolean isAnyIntersection = Arrays.stream(bricksEasy).anyMatch(ball2D::intersects);
```

Comment: Is this part of Java 8?

Comment: @Daniel Yoon  It is, indeed.

Comment: Yea I'm not too accustomed to Java 8 features besides lambda expressions :/

Comment: I understand. But I think that you should start to accustom to right now. Java 8 is not so young. Start with basics as Streams and predicates.